# EditBannedRequest doesn't work for bot in private channel

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

1. I have tried use the **EditBannedRequest** method for a private channel,
   when used it with a client works fine, however, when i use a bot
   with administrator permission over the channel, I got this error
   ***Main.telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.BotMethodInvalidError: The API
   access for bot users is restricted. The method you tried to invoke
   cannot be executed as a bot (caused by CheckChatInviteRequest)***
2. I handled EditBannedRequest method for receive directly valid
   entities without execute get_input_channel and get_input_entity
   methods... Then, I printed the values generated for the bot and
   compared with values generated for the client, and were equals.

For example:

In the Telegram method, I modified *resolve* function so:

```
async def resolve(self, client, utils):
        if isinstance(self.channel, InputChannel) and isinstance(self.user_id, InputUser):
            self.channel = self.channel
            self.user_id = self.user_id
        else:
            self.channel = utils.get_input_channel(await client.get_input_entity(self.channel))
            self.user_id = utils.get_input_user(await client.get_input_entity(self.user_id))
```

values generated by the client:
InputChannel(channel_id=XXXXXXX, access_hash=XXXXXX)
<class 'Main.telethon.tl.types.InputChannel'>

values sended by the bot:
INVITE_ACCESS = [InputChannel(channel_id=XXXXXXX, access_hash=XXXXXXX)]
USER = [InputUser(user_id=XXXXXXX, access_hash=-XXXXXXX)]

And the function is this:

```
with TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token) as bot:
    result = bot(functions.channels.EditBannedRequest(
        channel=INVITE_ACCESS[0],
        user_id=USER[0],
        banned_rights=types.ChatBannedRights(
            until_date=None,
            view_messages=True,
            send_messages=True
        )
    ))
    print(result.stringify())
```

The final error is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "banneduser.py", line 41, in <module>
    client(EditBannedRequest(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telethon/sync.py", line 39, in syncified
    return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 30, in _call_
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 77, in _call
    result = await future
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.ChannelInvalidError: Invalid channel object. Make sure to pass the right types, for instance making sure that the request is designed for channels or otherwise look for a different one more suited (caused by EditBannedRequest)
```

Any way to make the bot run the EditBannedRequest method without problems in a private channel?

Answer (score 2):

[`EditBannedRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/channels/edit_banned.html) can be used by bots just fine, but bots (like the error indicates) cannot use [`CheckChatInviteRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/check_chat_invite.html).

The `access_hash` is unique to each account (account A will see person C with hash 123, account B will see person C with has 456).

You should use the channel **peer** (or marked ID) to let Telethon know you're referring to a channel. Additionally, you should use [`client.edit_permissions`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.edit_permissions), which is nicer to use than raw API:

```py
chat = types.PeerChannel(123)
# chat = -100123  # equivalent, bot-API style channel ID

# Banning `user` from `chat` forever
await client.edit_permissions(chat, user, view_messages=False)
```